# JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to serialize all menu items and display the data with JS, in _Layout.cshtml.
It's MVC .Net 3.1 application. I'm getting `JsonException`: a possible object cycle was detected.

```
@inject ICategoryService _categoryService;
@inject IMenuItemService _menuItemService;
@using System.Text.Json;

@{
    var allMenuItems = _menuItemService.GetAllMenuItems();
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(allMenuItems)

}
```

I did some research and I add to startup.cs the following:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);

services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter>();
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
    }));
});
```

Unfortunately, it didn't fix my problem.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your exception details as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: 1) Why are you mixing Json.NET (via the call to `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`) and System.Text.Json (by using `SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter`)?  Which serializer do you want to use?

Comment: 2)  2) You have tagged this [tag:asp.net-mvc-3] and mention *MVC .Net 3.1*, but asp.net MVC 3 was [released in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC#Release_history) so you are probably using something else.  `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` was not even introduced until [.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.preserve?view=net-5.0#applies-to), so please [edit] your question to clarify what framework and version you are really using.